# How do I attach a public AND private reserved IP to a GCE instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance.html

I want to reserve a external and internal IP but how do I attach both? I dont see examples in tf docs.

It only has `network_ip - (Optional) The *private* IP address ...`
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance.html#network_interface

Comment: As a side question. Do you have a specific design requirement that requires assigning a static private IP address? Normally you let the DHCP server assign private IP addresses and you reference those instances with hostnames. Peering complicates this so there are valid reasons. Just food for thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a working example within my compute instance module:

```
resource "google_compute_address" "internal" {
  name         = "${var.NAME}-int-ip"
  subnetwork   = "${var.SUBNETWORK}"
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  address      = "${var.PRIVATE_IP}"
  region       = "${var.REGION}"
}

resource "google_compute_address" "external" {
  name         = "${var.NAME}-ext-ip"
  address_type = "EXTERNAL"
  region       = "${var.REGION}"
}
```

And then within the google_compute_instance resource block set the IP within the network_infrastructure block:

```
network_interface {
   network= "${var.NETWORK}"
   network_ip = "${google_compute_address.internal.address}"
   access_config {
      nat_ip = "${google_compute_address.external.address}" 
   }
```